# Why can't I uninstall a Unity game from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

Several months ago, I created a simple game using Unity 4.5 on an iMac running OS X Mavericks, and decided to try testing it on my iPhone 5s running iOS 7. I tested the game using the Unity Remote 4 app, and then closed out.

No longer interested in testing the game, I deleted Unity Remote a few days later. However, the game seems to have left some kind of "ghost app" behind on my phone — a blank app icon with my game's name that appears on my home screen. Upon tapping the icon, I am briefly presented with a black screen, and then returned to the home screen.

The app does not appear in Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage.

I have tried:

- Deleting the app from the home screen. This does not work, as the icon re-appears after rebooting.
- Using Xcode's Device view to delete the app. I was unable to do so due to "an internal API error."
- Restoring from backups, rebooting, and hard resetting ("force restarting"), but all to no avail.

I would like to avoid a full reset of my phone as I have a large amount of data that isn't, and cannot be, backed up to iCloud or other cloud services.

My phone is currently running iOS 8.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use iTunes to sync all apps you want except that one.

Answer (score 0):

A guess would be to use other file managers out there like ifunbox (you might need to jailbreak, not very sure). Try find the app u want to uninstall and see how it goes.
If it doesn't work, you can try to find alternatives. You may need to jailbreak for alternatives.